# I have contact information in raw form in a excel column. Need it organised in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have source data organised like this:

[image: Source data]

I would like to have it in rows like this:

`Sr. No.   Name    Address   Phone   Email`

Comment: Is this is one-time operation or do you need to do this with live or continuously updated data?

Comment: Basically i scanned a directory into pdf and then used OCR software to transfer it to excel. I just need all the contacts organised into rows so that i can use them for marketing and lead generation. Data isn't live, thanks

Comment: Hi Tetsujin. its mostly in caps already

Comment: What data can we rely on always being there? Can you update your screenshot to identify which column you want each row to be in? My best guess is that `Sr. No.` is one field and it's the line that starts `CA/`. `Name` is always the next row. `Phone` always starts with "Mobile". `Address` is everything between `Name` and `Phone`. `Email` always starts with "email". Is that right?

Comment: I have to ask, why is the place called PITAMPURA?! (In Pushpanjali). Translates to a very unfortunate name in English! :)

Comment: I tried testing another "AI" solution using Excel's Flashfill feature. If you place a TEXTJOIN formula next to every CA number, and join say all 8 rows below it into a single text field, you should be able to then copy those to a new sheets, filter out the blank rows and then use flashfill to pick out name, address, mobile etc automatically. I could not quite get it to work with only a sample dataset of 4 entries, but that's the beauty of flashfill. The more data you have, the more accurate it gets. That and absolutely no formulae!

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is not helpful to OP as their data is not consistently in sets of 8 rows. I'll leave it up for future reference of anyone who finds this question and *does* have data that's always the same number of rows.**

---

It looks like your data has the address on 3 lines. I would keep that as 3 columns in the results.

---

Assuming your data starts in cell A1, put this formula in cell B1:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),8)=1,OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-2,0),"")
```

Copy / paste that formula into the range `B1:I1` and the copy / paste that down however many rows you need. Now you have the data in rows. Since this is a one-time use, you can copy / paste values to get that data on a new sheet and then use Excel's filtering tools to remove all the blank rows.

Key Point: The `8` in the formula is because it appears that your data comes in sets of 8. If that is not always the case, this kind of solution will not work but the general concept can be reworked for that case.

[image: Screenshot]

---

If your data is reliably 8 rows AND you want to paste new data in the future and have it all automatically update, you can paste this thing wherever you want in the same sheet to get the filtered results:

```
=LET(lastRow,XLOOKUP(FALSE,ISBLANK($A:$A),ROW($A:$A),,,-1),seq,SEQUENCE(lastRow),col,TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(8)),data,IF(MOD(seq,8)<>1,"",INDEX($A:$A,seq+col-1)),FILTER(data,MOD(seq,8)=1))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey firstly thanks so much for making this effort. yes you're correct its not 8 rows reliably unfortunately. so you're solution starts off great but then runs into some trouble @EngineerToast

Comment: how do i add an image to show you what i mean. I'm quite new to this site

Comment: @ManavChopra Welcome! From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/help/formatting): Images can be added primarily by using the the [editor toolbar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCeyH.png). This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Note that the "rules" for determining what's what are in the comments. If your real data is not consistent, the rules will need to be changed. If this code doesn't work, be specific as to where your real data does not match with the examples you posted*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Rules:
//  Each entry starts with Serial Number CA/number/number
//     could simplify to just CA/ if that guaranteed to be non-ambiguous
//     or make it more complex if necessary
//  First row after SR will be name
//  All rows until phone number will be address
//  Phone number will always start with "MOBILE:"
//  email will always start with "email:"

//Add column so to be able to Group By ID
    #"Mark Serial Number" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Sr. No.", (sn)=>
        let 
            split = Text.Split(sn[Column1],"/"),
            verify = if List.Count(split) = 3
                        and split{0} = "CA"
                        and Value.Type(Number.FromText(split{1})) = type number
                        and Value.Type(Number.FromText(split{1})) = type number
                    then sn[Column1] else null
        in verify, type text),
    #"Grouper Column" = Table.FillDown(#"Mark Serial Number",{"Sr. No."}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Grouper Column", {"Sr. No."}, {
    
        {"Name", each [Column1]{1}, type text},
    
        {"Address", (t)=>Text.Combine(
                List.Select(List.RemoveFirstN(t[Column1],2), 
                    each not 
                        (Text.StartsWith(_,"MOBILE", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                         or Text.StartsWith(_, "email", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
                    "#(lf)"), type text},
    
        {"Phone", (t)=>
        Text.Trim(
            List.Last(
                Text.Split(
                    List.Select(t[Column1], 
                        each Text.StartsWith(_,"MOBILE", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){0},
                "MOBILE:"))),
                type text},
    
        {"Email", (t)=>Text.Trim(
            List.Last(
                Text.Split(
                    List.Select(t[Column1], 
                        each Text.StartsWith(_,"email:", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){0},
                "email:"))),
                type text}
      })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Original data***

| Column1 |
| --- |
| CA/2018/92890 |
| ABHISHEK CHHONKAR |
| B-39/F VUETA VIHAR DELHI POLICE |
| SOCIETY SECTOR-13, |
| ROHINI, DELHI, 110085, |
| DELHI |
| MOBILE: 8076426938 |
| email: abhishekehonkar@gmail.com |
| CA/2019/110870 |
| ABHISHEK GUPTA |
| 13-41/C, SOUTH GANESH NAGA, |
| DELHI, 110092, DELHI |
| MOBILE: 8510840769 |
| email: ar.abhishek7824@vnail.com |
| CA/2010/49509 |
| ABHISHEK JAIN |
| MUSE NO.2578, |
| GALI PEEPAL WALT, |
| DHARAMPURA, DELHI, 110006, |
| DELHI |
| MOBILE: 9811608229 |
| email: anabhishek Jain@yahoo.in |
| CA/2017/86603 |
| ABHISHEK JAIN |
| 59 SHUBH ENCLAVE, |
| PITAMPURA PUSHPANJALI, DELHI, |
| 110034, DELHI |
| MOBILE: 9999941389 |

***Results***

| Sr. No. | Name | Address | Phone | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA/2018/92890 | ABHISHEK CHHONKAR | B-39/F VUETA VIHAR DELHI POLICE SOCIETY SECTOR-13, ROHINI, DELHI, 110085, DELHI | 8076426938 | abhishekehonkar@gmail.com |
| CA/2019/110870 | ABHISHEK GUPTA | 13-41/C, SOUTH GANESH NAGA, DELHI, 110092, DELHI | 8510840769 | ar.abhishek7824@vnail.com |
| CA/2010/49509 | ABHISHEK JAIN | MUSE NO.2578, GALI PEEPAL WALT, DHARAMPURA, DELHI, 110006, DELHI | 9811608229 | anabhishek Jain@yahoo.in |
| CA/2017/86603 | ABHISHEK JAIN | 59 SHUBH ENCLAVE, PITAMPURA PUSHPANJALI, DELHI, 110034, DELHI | 9999941389 | abhisheksinghaljain@gmail.com |

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- The last row in each data entry starts with "email:"
- The first two rows in an entry are "Sr. No." and "Name"
- The last two rows in an entry are "Phone" and "Email"
- Everything in between the first two and last two are the address

---

**Solution:**

You can do this with pure formulas but it'll take several. First, insert a row above your data. I filled this in with column headers to help me keep track of what I was doing but it's really just there to make the formula in the "Last Email" field (Column C) easier to input. The final result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

| **Field Name** | **Formula Cell** | **Formula** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IsEmail | B2 | `=UPPER(LEFT(A2,6))="EMAIL:"` |
| Last Email | C2 | `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/B1:B$2,ROW(B1:B$2)),1)` |
| Sr. No. | D2 | `=IF(NOT(B2),"",INDEX(A:A,C2+1))` |
| Name | E2 | `=IF(NOT(B2),"",INDEX(A:A,C2+2))` |
| Address | F2 | `=IF(NOT(B2),"",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,OFFSET($A$1,C2+2,0,ROW()-C2-4)),", ,",",,"),",,",","))` |
| Phone | G2 | `=IF(NOT(B2),"",A1)` |
| Email | H2 | `=IF(NOT(B2),"",A2)` |

That big Address formula is made longer with the double `SUBSTITUTE()` to clean up the double commas. Many of your address pieces include a comma at the end already so I tried to clean that up via formula. If you clean that data manually (before or after), the formula in F2 can be this:

```
=IF(NOT($B2),"",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,OFFSET($A$1,C2+2,0,ROW()-C2-4)))
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `IsEmail` field just finds the last row of an entry by checking for the fixed string. `Last Email` finds the *previous* end of an entry by looking for the last `TRUE` value in `IsEmail`. If it doesn't find one, then it must be the first entry so we use the value `1` instead because what we *really* care about is the start and end of the current entry.

Once we have those two values, pulling most everything else is easy. The address is a little tricky because we have to concatenate some number of cells but we can use the difference between the beginning and end of the data entry to figure out how many rows the address is.

Once you rows that are either blank or have a single entry on them, you copy / paste values elsewhere and use Excel's filtering tools to remove the blanks. This solution leaves in text like "email:" in the email address and "Mobile:" in the phone number but those are trivial to remove either in the formulas or as part of post-processing.